# Baby stroller + car seat in Wizzair flights - how much?

Tags: wizz-air

I'm flying with Wizzair and want to take both a baby car seat and a stroller. I understand that one is free of charge, and the other one needs to be paid for.

Does anyone have an idea how much? I tried looking at the Wizzair website or contacting them, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this, there is a list of fees for excess baggage.

Here's the fees (as of july 18 2019)

https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/prices-discounts/all-services-fees

Baggage fee low season max. 10 kg 
WIZZAIR.COM & CALL CENTRE   Per flight, per passenger and per bag   ‎€9.00 – ‎€24.00

Baggage fee high season max. 10 kg 
WIZZAIR.COM & CALL CENTRE   Per flight, per passenger and per bag   ‎€12.00 – ‎€27.00

Baggage fee low season max. 20 kg 
WIZZAIR.COM & CALL CENTRE   Per flight, per passenger and per bag   ‎€15.00 – ‎€44.00

Baggage fee high season max. 20 kg 
WIZZAIR.COM & CALL CENTRE   Per flight, per passenger and per bag   ‎€20.00 – ‎€50.00

Baggage fee low season max. 32 kg 
WIZZAIR.COM & CALL CENTRE   Per flight, per passenger and per bag   ‎€23.00 – ‎€63.00

Baggage fee high season max. 32 kg 
WIZZAIR.COM & CALL CENTRE   Per flight, per passenger and per bag   ‎€31.00 – ‎€72.00

Baggage fee low season max. 20 kg 
AIRPORT Per flight, per passenger and per bag   ‎€55.00

Baggage fee low season max. 32 kg 
AIRPORT Per flight, per passenger and per bag   ‎€110.00

Sports equipment 
WIZZAIR.COM & CALL CENTRE   Per flight, per passenger and per bag   ‎€30.00

Sports equipment 
AIRPORT Per flight, per passenger and per bag   ‎€60.00

Baggage excess weight fee 
AIRPORT Per kilo, per item, per flight  ‎€10.00

High season:

19 December 2018 - 13 January 2019
Easter 19 peak: 13 April 2019– 28 April 2019
Summer 19 peak: 16 June 2019 – 22 September 2019

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could quote the details. Links can change/expire/go dead and then it's a useless link :/